# Files in the data directory (Upload | Custom)should not be downloadable. (Nginx)

Tags: drupal, security, nginx

I am running a drupal site on nginx and I have a civicrm set-up on this site. Whenever I login and goto civicrm dashboard, I am getting this warnings. I have tried searching solution for this, not able to fix it.

```
Files in the data directory (/home/drupal7/sites/example.org/files/civicrm/custom/) should not be downloadable.

Read more about this warning

Files in the data directory (/home/drupal7/sites/example.org/files/civicrm/upload/) should not be downloadable.

Read more about this warning
```

I have tried this on my nginx configuration file.

```
    root /home/drupal7;

    location ~ /sites/example.org/files/civicrm/(custom|upload) {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proposed solution in your nginx config looks about right; here's a tested & working example:

```
location ~* ^/sites/(.*)/files/civicrm/(ConfigAndLog|templates_c|upload|custom) {
    deny all;
}
```

Here are some things you could check.

1. Have you reloaded nginx since making the config change?
2. Pick a file in files/civicrm/custom/ and try to access it in a browser.

   - If you can, the nginx config needs fixing.
   - If you can't, the warning is spurious; it would be good to investigate why. Check your nginx access logs for the test requests that Civi makes to check access.
3. Is another `location` block in your nginx config taking precedence over this one? You can check this by temporarily enabling debug-level logging for the relevant virtual host, e.g.

   error_log /path/to/log debug;

(Note that nginx needs to have been built with --with-debug .)
This will produce very verbose logging, so only enable it briefly while testing: enable debug, access a file under files/civicrm/custom/ , disable debug, then look through your error log for the request. From this, you should be able to see which `location` block matched the request.

You should also deny access to ConfigAndLog/ and templates_c/ as in the config above.

See [checkUploadsAreNotAccessible](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/checkUploadsAreNotAccessible).

Comment: thanks. it's working. I tested it as well. One gotcha here though. This config should be on top of the other. Since I had location directive set for `*.jpg` files to expire max and I was able to browse jpg files under upload directory. now that I have set this on top (below root) this is working fine now. :) Thanks much.

Comment: Is there a way to correct this issue without configuring nginx? I am hosting on pantheon and don't have access to nginx configs

Comment: @YossiCrm Not that I know of. Nginx doesn't use .htaccess files, which are used to configure Civi's per-directory access restrictions under Apache.