# Civicrm with Nginx and Joomla - resource URLs and configuration file

Tags: joomla, css, resource-urls, nginx

Joomla 3.9.2
CiviCRM 5.11.0

If I set up nginx to not protect the custom files directory, CiviCRM gives a warning that some files are downloadable. Fair enough.

But if I set up nginx to protect the custom files directory, this apparently prevents CiviCRM from reading the custom css file in the custom files directory. I assume that this is not the intended behaviour.

How can I set up nginx so that a) the custom files directory is protected and b) CiviCRM reads the custom css?

I am using the configuration setup suggested in [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4042/files-in-the-data-directory-upload-customshould-not-be-downloadable-nginx), but it doesn't appear to fix the problem for me (possibly because Joomla not Drupal). Could it be that this is a problem only for Joomla CiviCRM?

Comment: See the answer posted in response to [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4042/files-in-the-data-directory-upload-customshould-not-be-downloadable-nginx?noredirect=1&lq=1).